# ListIterator next and previous. Detail

Tags: java, iterator

So by reading this from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#next%28%29

*emphasized text*

> E next()
>
> ```
> Returns the next element in the list. This method may be called repeatedly
> ```
>
> previous to go back and forth. (**Note that alternating calls to next
>   and previous will return the same element repeatedly**.)

I understand what they mean with

> **Note that alternating calls to next
>   and previous will return the same element repeatedly**

However I haven't found in the javadoc how it happens. I guess that it's due that after `iterator.next()` the "cursor" goes in the next position automatically after having returned the current element? Might be? So in that case a call to `iterator.previous()` would just return the same element and set back the cursor to where it was prior to calling `iterator.next()`.

Comment: If you read the introduction of the javadoc, the cursor is placed between items.

Comment: @assylias I am aware of that, thanks a lot for reminding it though.

Comment: let's say you cursor is before n-th element, `next` will return `n` and place the cursor after the n-th element. If you call `previous`, it will return `n` again and place the cursor before the n-th element, etc. So your assumption *I guess that it's due that after iterator.next() the "cursor" goes in the next position automatically after having returned the current element?* is correct.

Comment: @assylias thanks a lot for confirming it. cheers!